# How to properly synchronize concurrent reads and writes on a AsynchronousSocketChannel

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency, nio, vert.x

I am trying to implement a single request/response on a AsynchronousSocketChannel in a vert.x worker verticle using CompletionHandler not Futures. From the vert.x documentation:

> "Worker verticles are never executed concurrently by more than one thread."

So here is my code (not sure I got the socket handling 100% right - please comment):

```
    // ommitted: asynchronousSocketChannel.open, connect ...

    eventBus.registerHandler(address, new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(final Message<JsonObject> event) {
            final ByteBuffer receivingBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2048);
            final ByteBuffer sendingBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("Foo".getBytes());

            asynchronousSocketChannel.write(sendingBuffer, 0L, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Long>() {
                public void completed(final Integer result, final Long attachment) {
                    if (sendingBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                        long newFilePosition = attachment + result;
                        asynchronousSocketChannel.write(sendingBuffer, newFilePosition, this);
                    }

                    asynchronousSocketChannel.read(receivingBuffer, 0L, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Long>() {
                        CharBuffer charBuffer = null;
                        final Charset charset = Charset.defaultCharset();
                        final CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();

                        public void completed(final Integer result, final Long attachment) {
                            if (result > 0) {
                                long p = attachment + result;
                                asynchronousSocketChannel.read(receivingBuffer, p, this);
                            }

                            receivingBuffer.flip();

                            try {
                                charBuffer = decoder.decode(receivingBuffer);
                                event.reply(charBuffer.toString()); // pseudo code
                            } catch (CharacterCodingException e) { }


                        }

                        public void failed(final Throwable exc, final Long attachment) { }
                    });
                }

                public void failed(final Throwable exc, final Long attachment) { }
            });
        }
    });
```

I am hitting a lot of ReadPendingException's and WritePendingException's during load testing which seems a bit strange if there is really only one thread at a time in the handle method. How can it be that a read or a write has not fully completed if there is only 1 thread working with the AsynchronousSocketChannel at a time?

Comment: You have more than one handler. They could be executed at the same time. I assume this is just an exercise because this code would not only be simpler using blocking IO or NIO, it might be a lot faster too. From the testing I have done NIO2 is tuned for Infini-band rather than Ethernet.

Comment: Yes one CompletionHandler which might read again and one CompletionHandler which might write again - which should be okay since AysnchronousSocketChannel supports concurrent reads and writes (full duplex). Actually this is not an excercise, I want to use this to send a command to Redis and get the response without blocking.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid blocking?

Comment: Because I don't want to wait for the DB to respond but rather be notified if the result is ready.

Comment: BTW: Your read might not read all the result at once, so you need to detect when you have a complete result. If you use the same connection for more than once query you need to workout where one ends and the next one starts (which could be in the same read())

Answer (score 1):

Handlers from AsynchronousSocketChannel are executed on their own AsynchronousChannelGroup which is a derivative of ExecutorService. Unless you make special efforts, that handlers are executed in parallel with the code which started I/O operation.

To execute I/O completion handler within a verticle, you have to make and register a handler from that verticle which does what AsynchronousSocketChannel's handler do now.

The AsynchronousSocketChannel's handler should only pack its arguments (result and attachment) in a message and sent that message to the event bus.

Comment: You mean the first thing in the CompletionHandler is to send another message to the EventBus and then have a vert.x Handler doing what the CompletionHandler does now? I think this only works if the worker verticle who sent the message will also be the one receiving it (since every worker will have it's own AsynchronousSocketChannel). Also sending result and attachment is tricky because you can send only certain object types to the event bus.

Comment: @user1671319 yes the address of message receiver should be passed to the original handler, so attachment has to be a complex structure {newFilePosition, address}. The message also has to be a structure. As a result, your code become like spaghetti. The vert.x manual mentions that "it in some ways resembles the actor model". Resembles is right word here - one have to keep in mind mapping between true actor picture and vert.x implementation. Meanwile, an actor interface to NIO2 which is much closer to classic actor model exists: df4j-nio2 in https://github.com/rfqu/df4j (yes its mine)